How to do Flow designer and SLA in service now
[flow design ]
sla (https://i.sstatic.net/pSCYGJfg.png) flow design in the first picture wherein workflow and notification are in need in flow design and next is service level agreement.
Workflow:

If Request Type is Request group membership, add an approval to the Group Manager.
If request was approved, add the user automatically to the group, then set the RITM state to Closed Complete.
If Approval was rejected, set RITM to Closed Incomplete.
If the user is already part of the group, set the RITM to Closed Skipped.
If Request Type is Remove group membership or Remove all group membership, create a Catalog Task for with the short description ‘Group Membership Removal’ assigned to ‘Group Membership Admin’ group (this is for manual request fulfillment).
If Catalog Task state is set to Closed Complete, and the user was completely removed from the group/s, set RITM state to Closed Complete. If not, set RITM state to Closed Incomplete.
If Catalog Task state is set to Closed Incomplete, set RITM state to Closed Incomplete.

Notifications:

If Request Type is Request group membership and Requested For is not the currently logged in user, notify the Group Manager and the Requested For, otherwise, notify only the Group Manager. In case the user is already part of the group, include this detail in the notification.

If Request Type is Remove group membership or Remove all group membership and Requested For is not the currently logged in user, notify the Requested For and the Opened By, otherwise, notify only the Requested For.
*Note:  Include every group name that will be added or removed in the notification content



Create shared SLA definitions for these groups with the additional requirements:
•   The SLA triggers Depending on the priority of the incident. If priority changed, the SLA triggers the SLA for that specific priority. (Priority1 = 20 mins / Priority2 = 40 mins / Priority3 = 60 mins / Priority4 = 2 Hours/ Priority5 = 5 Hours)
•   If SLA triggers new SLA because of the changing on priority, the start date/time of the SLA must the same from the previous one. Previous SLA must be cancelled.
•   SLA Schedule is from 8am to 5pm, Sunday to Thursday, Dubai time zone.
Send a notification to the assigned person of the incident once the SLA only left 30% of the time.
